# VS Code Java Output 'HelloWorld' with the blue things

Tags: java, visual-studio, output, visual-studio-code

I downloaded VS Code Java and tried to run the code and the output looked like this. The 'HelloWorld' can be printed but it comes with some blue things. Is this normal? I am not sure if I will get into other issues as I get start developing other classes and trying to call one another.

[image: This is my output]

Comment: It's just telling you what commands it used to run your program.

Answer (score 1):

The text in blue is the program that VSCode executes behind the scenes in order to run your code. You needn't worry about it.